# Questions about Transpose Matrix Properties

Tags: matrices, transpose

It is a specific doubt about one exercise related to matrix operations with transpose.

How can we simplify this operation: $(A - B)^T$ * $(A - B)$ ?

How can this [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OtpZ.png) lead to [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnBMk.png)?

I haven't seen any matrix property that could explain that.

Edit: Please let me know if the questions are not well formulated.

Thank you.

Comment: In your example the computation is:$$(A-B)^T (A-B)=(A^T-B^T)(A-B)=A^T A  -A^T B -B^T A+B^T B$$

Comment: Thanks @Delta-u, but in the images that I attached, it looks like he differentiates ($-A^T*B-B^T*A$) and that ($B^T*B = B^2$). I think he might be wrong there.

Comment: These are dot product of *vectors* written in matrix form. Every term of the form $\mathbf v^T\mathbf w$ is a *scalar*, which allows for a lot of rearrangement of expressions. Often these manipulations make use of the fact that the transpose of a scalar is just the same scalar, so that $\mathbf v^T\mathbf w=\mathbf w^T\mathbf v$.